# xorg: one physical monitor with multiple virtual screens

Tags: xorg

Is it possible to configure xserver to support one physical monitor with multiple virtual screens?
The [fakexrandr](https://github.com/phillipberndt/fakexrandr) project can fake one physical monitor with multiple virtual monitors but not screens.